# After Minification on website page is not loading in safari 9.1 properly AEM 6.0

Tags: adobe, aem

website is working fine in every browser without minification but after minification on all the page which is using angular is not loading properly in safari 9.1 .There is no angular or js error available in console.

what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is most likely the YUI compressor which is outdated and in case you use "modern" language features, the compression breaks. I don't know which version of AEM you are using, but perhaps this article helps:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/how-to-change-the-minification-engine-for-client-libraries-in-AEM.html

You should try to minify with the Google Closure compiler.